# collada_parser build failed on raspberry pi 3 (jessie debian), ros indigo

Tags: rasbperrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a similar error with collada_parser as mentioned [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/226253/trouble-installing-indigo-on-debian-jessie-collada_parser-build-failure/) but the described solution from @Humpelstilzchen didnt work for me and apparently also not for another user (or I am doing something wrong).
First, I installed collada-dom-dev according to the [guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

I ran checkinstall and changed the name immediately to collada-dom-dev. After installation, I used the sudo ldconfig -v command and:

```
/usr/local/lib:
liburdfdom_model.so.1.0 -> liburdfdom_model.so.1.0
liburdfdom_sensor.so.1.0 -> liburdfdom_sensor.so.1.0
libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.0 -> libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.2.4.0
liburdfdom_world.so.1.0 -> liburdfdom_world.so.1.0
liburdfdom_model_state.so.1.0 -> liburdfdom_model_state.so.1.0
```

showed up.
Running a dpkg-query -l 'collada*' shows that the package is installed.

```
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
-====================-===============-===============-==============================================
un  collada-dom          <none>          <none>          (no description available)
ii  collada-dom-dev      2.4.0-1         armhf           Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2
```

I also applied the collada_urdf.cpp fix.
Finally, I applied the remaining depencies and the workspace:

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:jessie
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j1
```

The error i got is:

```
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_parser/src/collada_parser.cpp:2434:59: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘((urdf::ColladaModelReader*)this)->urdf::ColladaModelReader::_model.boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-><urdf::ModelInterface>()->urdf::ModelInterface::joints_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         if (_model->joints_.find(name) == _model->joints_.end()) {
                                                           ^
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_parser/src/collada_parser.cpp:2437:38: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘((urdf::ColladaModelReader*)this)->urdf::ColladaModelReader::_model.boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-><urdf::ModelInterface>()->urdf::ModelInterface::joints_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
             pjoint = _model->joints_.find(name)->second;
                                      ^
CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:91: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'collada_parser': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j1
```

Running the reproducing command fails with:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:91: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all' failed
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

The only difference to the guide is that i had to run the last command twice because had to increase the raspberries swap space. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247523/collada_parser-build-failed-on-raspberry-pi-3-(jessie-debian),-ros-indigo/) by [jabberwox](https://answers.ros.org/users/28431/jabberwox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-11-08**:
do you have more output?

**Comment by [jabberwox](https://answers.ros.org/users/28431/jabberwox/) on 2016-11-09**:
Edited the output lines in the post. Are you interested in a specific output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a totally different error then the one you linked. This looks like an incompatibility, I suggest to create a bug against [robot model](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0